# jQuery descendents of filtered out parents are still in the collection

Tags: jquery

Goal: **no** red outlines on p tags inside of .third classes.

Self-contained example below, or jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/WJVBm/

Desperately looking forward to awarding a green checkmark... Thanks in advance for any help!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var myDivs = $('div');

        var myFilteredDivs = myDivs.filter(function(){
            return $(this).closest('.third').length == 0;
        });

        var myFilteredParagraphs = myFilteredDivs.find('p'); // why does this find paragraphs in divs that have already been filtered out of the collection?

        myDivs.css('border', '1px solid #CCC');
        myFilteredDivs.css('border', '1px solid blue');
        myFilteredParagraphs.css('border', '1px solid red'); // paragraphs inside of divs that should not exist in the collection are still being outlined by a red border

    });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        div { float: left; padding: 20px; margin: 5px; }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="first">
        <p>first</p>
        <div class="second">
            <p>second</p>
            <div class="third">
                <p>third</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="second">
            <p>second2</p>
        </div>
        <div class="third">
            <p>third2</p>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's because they're also the descendants of other, non-filtered elements. Depending on your actual markup, you might get away by using `children()` instead of `find()`.

Comment: The problem is that `myDivs` contains each div and its nested children in each match.  
Add the `console.log(myDivs);` and you can see it in the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/3JALD/

It probably can be improved but it seems to do what you need.

All of the paragraphs were found for `myFilteredParagraphs` because `div.first` was part of `myFilteredDivs` and `find()` gets all of the `p`s that are descendent from `div.first`.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a very simple, maybe obvious fix:

http://jsfiddle.net/WJVBm/13/

```
var myFilteredParagraphs = myFilteredDivs.find('> p'); // why does this find paragraphs in divs that have already been filtered out of the collection?
```

use the direct child selector `>`

Does that do what you're looking for?